# GET call with access_token in the Header

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex

I am creating a Third Party Application with Oracle Apex.
I have enabled protection on the Apex Server and In order to access any resource I have to append a custom Header Authorization: With a Bearer token. The token is known to me before hand.

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/avi_eval/gallery/images/21

My HTML code is as follows:-
    
    
    HTML Editor Sample Page

### [Click Here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/avi_eval/gallery/images/21)

If I press Click Here I want the image to be displayed in the same page or a different page.

So my GET HTTP Request should look like this:-
GET {url above}
Request Header:-
Content/Type: text/html; charset =UTF-8
...
...
Authorization :Bearer abcdefgh..

How can I do this?

Comment: what is this `Authorization : Bearer access_token`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using javascript

```
<a href="URL" onclick="this.href=this.href+'?access_token='+header_val">click here</a>
```

Comment: My get request should look something like this
GET http://abc.com/xyz
Content-Length 277
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
..
..
Authorization: Bearer abcdefgh...

Comment: I am not looking to append to the HTTP URL. But to the HTTP Request Header.